# iptables to redirect DNS queries on bridge

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables

Setup:

`Router -> (eth0)Server(eth1) -> Switch -> devices`

```
#/etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual
iface eth1 inet manual

#allow-hotplug br0
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
bridge_ports eth0 eth1
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

How to setup iptables so that DNS queries from all devices connected to eth1 are forwarded to the sever itself ? Address : 192.168.1.2

Comment: Can you not just configure the devices to use 192.168.1.2 s their DNS server ?

Comment: did you see http://serverfault.com/questions/499435/gateway-iptables-dns-redirect or http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144482/iptables-to-redirect-dns-lookup-ip-and-port or http://serverfault.com/questions/298092/redirecting-dns-port-to-a-specific-dns-server ??